# Convert xml ntext in mssql to csv (ucomponents migration)

Tags: sql-server, xml, csv, umbraco

I have lots of rows in an mssql table which are in xml format and I want to convert them to csv. The column is an ntext and the values are like.

```
<MultiNodePicker type="content">
  <nodeId>5713</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6817</nodeId>
  <nodeId>5424</nodeId>
  <nodeId>1888</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6128</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6339</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>
```

and I would like to convert them in 5713,6817,5424,1888,6128,6339
Any ideas how to achieve this with sql command?

** Probably this seems to be the way to go https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/780e80b2-f898-4451-b19f-332289fb1c8d/sql-xml-get-xml-values-into-csv?forum=sqlxml , save it in a function and then loop through all the rows and update the values. At the moment it is failing at x.y.value.

I tried also to use replace but it failed because it is xml and it doesnt get the space between the xml nodes.

I also used

```
set dataNvarchar = substring(CAST(dataNtext as nvarchar(500)), patindex('%[0-9]%', CAST(dataNtext as nvarchar(500))), 1+patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', CAST(dataNtext as nvarchar(500))+'x')-patindex('%[0-9]%', CAST(dataNtext as nvarchar(500))))
```

but it gets only the first numeric.

******* Additional Solution *********
These values come from uComponent plugin for Umbraco. I couldn't find a way to read it as xml - even though the solution to this as proper xml is correct.
Instead I wrote this function which solved my problem

```
Create Function [dbo].[ParseXml](@text ntext) 
returns nvarchar(500) as 
Begin 
declare @strnvar nvarchar(MAX) -- main string to subtruct
declare @numberstr nvarchar(500) -- extracted number
declare @csvstr nvarchar(500) -- constructed csv string
-- Convert text to nvarchar
set @strnvar = CAST(@text as nvarchar(MAX))
set @csvstr = ''
set @numberstr = substring(@strnvar, patindex('%[0-9]%', @strnvar), 1 + patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @strnvar+'x') - patindex('%[0-9]%', @strnvar))

while(DATALENGTH(@numberstr) > 0)
BEGIN 
set @csvstr = @csvstr + @numberstr + ','
set @strnvar = REPLACE(@strnvar, @numberstr, '')
set @numberstr = substring(@strnvar, patindex('%[0-9]%', @strnvar), 1 + patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @strnvar+'x') - patindex('%[0-9]%', @strnvar))
END

IF RIGHT(@csvstr,1) = ',' 
    set @csvstr =  LEFT(@csvstr, LEN(@csvstr) - 1)
return @csvstr
end 
GO
```

Comment: The first thing would be to convert your existing column to nvarchar. The text and ntext datatypes have been deprecated for over a decade now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql In fact, if this is truly xml data you should use the xml datatype. Then you can use STUFF to generate the delimited list like you want.

Comment: That is what I have in mind but the best that I achieved was to get only the numeric of the first node.

Comment: Can you share some ddl, sample data and what you have tried? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I updated the description with the things I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert ntext to xml then you can build comma separated as below

```
declare @x xml = '<MultiNodePicker type="content">
  <nodeId>5713</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6817</nodeId>
  <nodeId>5424</nodeId>
  <nodeId>1888</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6128</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6339</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>'

Select Stuff(( Select ','+ y.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)')
FROM @x.nodes(N'MultiNodePicker/nodeId') as x(y) for xml path('') ),1,1,'')
```

Output as below:

```
5713,6817,5424,1888,6128,6339
```

I created function as below and it is working fine:

```
Create Function [dbo].[ParseXml](@text ntext) returns nvarchar(500) as 
Begin declare @x xml = @text 
return 
Stuff(( Select ',' + y.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(MAX)') FROM @x.nodes(N'MultiNodePicker/nodeId') as x(y) for xml path('')),1,1,'') 
end 


declare @x nvarchar(500) = '<MultiNodePicker type="content">
  <nodeId>5713</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6817</nodeId>
  <nodeId>5424</nodeId>
  <nodeId>1888</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6128</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6339</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>'

select  dbo.ParseXml(@x)
```

Output : Same as above

Comment: I have made a scalar function where on return Stuff(( Select ','+ y.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') FROM @x.nodes(N'MultiNodePicker/nodeId') as x(y) for xml path('') ),1,1,'') I got the message cannot find either column y or the user defined aggregate is rather ambiguous. What am I missing?

Comment: how you are passing to function? can you show the function details?

Comment: CREATE Function [dbo].[ParseXml](@text ntext)
returns nvarchar(500) as
Begin
 declare @x xml = @text
 return Stuff(( Select ',' + y.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(MAX)') FROM @x.nodes(N'MultiNodePicker/nodeId') as x(y) for xml path('')),1,1,'')
end
GO

Comment: Not sure what error you are getting... But updated answer is working fine from my end

Comment: I tried it also directly in update but I still have the same issue (XML parsing: line 13, character 22, well formed check: undeclared entity)

Comment: Do u have &, <,> chars in data?

Comment: All the ntext values are like the example. Sql highlights with red the y.value before executing the code.

Comment: In any case Ill take your answer as right the format of the xml is probably not correct. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @text varchar(max) = '<MultiNodePicker type="content">
  <nodeId>5713</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6817</nodeId>
  <nodeId>5424</nodeId>
  <nodeId>1888</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6128</nodeId>
  <nodeId>6339</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>'


declare @xml xml = @text;


select
t.c.query('.').value('.', 'int') as NodeId
from @xml.nodes('/MultiNodePicker/nodeId') t(c)
```